# Easy ways to make apperance of custom controls adjustable in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, styling

I am currently adding a dependency property for everything I want to adjust in my custom controls. However, I am dreaming of an easier or less verbose way to archieve it.

Here is an example:
I have a custom Button and one of its features is to display the keybindings it is bound to. I want this textblock to be styleable from the outside, so I add a handful of dependency properties to the control, like: HotkeyTextFontSize, HotKeytextFontStyle, HotKeyTextForeground, HotKeyTextMargin.

This bugs me, because it is firstly too much and secondly I might forget some things which someone want to style later on.

Are there other ways to do it?? Opinions and tips are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: You can style those in a style and make it more manageable, but I don't think you can do much about it. Default values would save some of the hassle.

Comment: wow, bad way....when creating custom controls, define the PART_xxx and then the designer will be able to change it as he want in another style - good starting sample : http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-part-names

Comment: @XAMlMAX Do you mean adding a dependency property like HotKeyTextStyle ? However, won't the style need to be completely rewritten if someone wants to change only one property like FontSize?

Comment: @GCamel I will check that out, thank you

Comment: I mean keep the properties like `FontSizeProperty` or `FontFamilyProperty` if you apply a style for that custom control like this  `Style TargetType="{x:Type custom:FancyButton}">` then you can access those from that style and change them accordingly when used in different parts, chances are you will mostly change the text of the bound key, if you need more than you will override those properties. What you will do in style is whatever you are doing to any other UI control. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I understood, thank you. @XAMlMAX

Comment: One of the advantages of custom controls is you can easily re-skin by replacing their template. Maybe you should explain why this isn't what you mean. Assuming that is the case :^)

Comment: The "WPF way" would be to expose a content template to the user rather then exposing each individual property. You would define a default content template and the user can override it if they want. Content templates only allow customization of the actual control and not any frame around the popup or anything like that. Take a look at how tool tips work for an example. The content template doesn't define how the tooltip itself looks like, but just the stuff inside of it.

Comment: I did some research and got it now. Do you want to answer the question @SledgeHammer? I could provide some of the details of my research in the comment-section of your answer.